# How can I calculate a cascade sales discount scenario using TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Consider a table containing 3 DiscountPrograms, with assigned calculation order

```
create table program (programid varchar(5), calc_order tinyint)

go

insert tblprogram(programid, calc_order)
values(prog1, 1)

insert tblprogram(programid, calc_order)
values(prog2, 2)

insert tblprogram(programid, calc_order)
values(prog3, 3)

go
```

... and a table of products that are assigned a to program

```
create table tblproduct(productid varchar(11), programid varchar(5))

go

insert tblproduct(productid, programid)
values(productabc, prog1)
insert tblproduct(productid, programid)
values(productdef, prog2)
insert tblproduct(productid, programid)
values(productxyz, prog3)

go
```

... and a table of sales by product

```
create table tblsales(productid varchar(11), salesamount numeric(18,2))

go 

insert tblsales(productid, salesamount)
values(productabc, 150)

insert tblsales(productid, salesamount)
values(productdef, 500)

insert tblsales(productid, salesamount)
values(productxyz, 650)

go
```

Sales for a product belonging to prog1 are given a 1% discount:

.01*productabcSales

or...

.01*150 = 1.50

Sales for a product belonging to prog2 are given a discount of 1% of (sales minus the previous discount applied by prog1):

.01*(productdefSales-(.01*productabcSales))

or...

.01*(500-(.01*150) = 4.985

Sales for a product belonging to prog3 are given a 2% rebate, against the salesamount minus (the amounts already paid out by prog2 minus (the payout by prog1)):

.02*(productxyzSales-(.01*(productdefSales-(.01*productabcSales))))

or...

.02*(650-(.01*(500-(.01*150))))) = 12.9003

I am thinking there must be an easy way to do this without creating a bunch of temp tables?  Maybe CTE??  Also, there can be any number of programs in play...

Comment: I created a SQL Fiddle, though now I don't think I have time to try to answer the question.  :)  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51142

Comment: Yes, a CTE should be able to process the discounts recursively.

Comment: As you've defined them, there's no actual need to process them in order.

Comment: only need is the crazy rules for the rebate program that were invented by the business.

Comment: Where does the information come from that correlates the discount/rebate amount to the productid, and orders them? That is, how do we know that the percentages are 0.1, 0.1, and 0.2; how do we know they are in this order; and how do we know they apply (respectively) to products abc, def, and xyz? If there are 25 products and 30 programs, what are the values? Without all this information, there is no way I could give you a generalized solution to your problem. And for what it's worth: I am confident you don't need looping or cursors.

Comment: P.S. Very important: What version of SQL Server? 2000, 2005, 2008, 2013, what?

Comment: We are running SQL 2008

Comment: The calc_order values in tblprograms is maintained by the business via .NET interface and correlates the program to the calculation order.  The calculation order is ordered from 1 to n asc, with 1 being the first program and is calculated against raw sales amount. The tblproduct table correlates the product to the program. The Sales table contains the sales by product.

Comment: @user3108433 Thank you for the answers. You still didn't answer where the discount percentages come from. Also, is there always a one-to-one correspondence between program and sale? That is, could there be only 2 programs and 3 sales, or 20 programs and 5 sales? Please tag people in your comments so they know you responded (when there is more than one other person in the comment stream, no one is automatically notified of a new comment except the post owner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a set based kludge that is simply trying to avoid the fact that a cursor is the correct approach for this problem...  (one of the very, very, very rare occasions where that statement is true)

I added a `discount` column to your `tblprogram` table - as that seemed the right place to put it - but I, obviously, have no real idea of your use case (so you will want to adjust my code accordingly).

I use `ROW_NUMBER()` to make sure the `calc_order` values start at 1 and are contiguous (so that the code later works).  The `order by` in the `over()` should remove any random behaviour if there are ties in the `calc_order` from your `tblprogram` table.  Obviously this is all just me being cautious - you know your data better than me - so if this code is over defensive, use you `calc_order` directly.

```
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by prg.calc_order, prg.programid) as calc_order, 
    s.productid, 
    p.programid, 
    prg.discount, --  this is the additional column to hold your values
    s.salesamount,
    convert(decimal(7,5),0) as rebate
into #results
from tblsales s
join tblproduct p on p.productid=s.productid 
join tblprogram prg on prg.programid=p.programid

declare @calc_order int=1

while @@ROWCOUNT>0 begin

    update r set
        rebate=(r.salesamount-isnull((
                select rebate
                from #results 
                where calc_order=@calc_order-1
                ),0))*discount,
        @calc_order+=1
    from #results r
    where r.calc_order=@calc_order

end

select * 
from #results
```

produces:-

```
calc_order  productid   programid  discount  salesamount  rebate
1           productabc  prog1      0.01      150.00       1.50000
2           productdef  prog2      0.01      500.00       4.98500
3           productxyz  prog3      0.02      650.00       12.90030
```

And just to head off the inevitable down votes for suggesting a cursor is the right way to go - if the `while` loop was a cursor - the `select` embedded in the `update` would not be required because you would inevitably have kept a running total of the rebate so far - avoiding work for the server.  I cannot see how a recursive cte would avoid this either.  If you want me to throw the cursor code into here, drop a message below, and I'll add it.

Comment: I ended up going with cursor.  Tried everything I could think of to avoid it, but is as you said - the right tool in this rare case.  Cheers!

Comment: Also I don't believe in over-defensive... ALWAYS code on-purpose!